# Standard Deviation of Non-Rectangular Array

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I have a list of about 700 smaller lists, most with different dimensions. They range from 1 element to 18 elements long.

Think like:

```
lst = {{1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6}, {7,8,9,10}, ...}
```

I simply want to take the standard deviation of each inner list, but for the life of me cannot figure out how. Ideally, my final list should be one dimensional. I have tried several workarounds, but they all come back to the problem of it being non-rectangular. I feel like it should be simple, and would love any ideas because I am stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Take a look at [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html). You can use it like ``Map[StandardDeviation, lst]`` or with a shorthand notation ``StandardDeviation /@ lst``. However, note that ``StandardDeviation`` calculates the _sample_ std. dev., which cannot be calculated for one element. You can also calculate _population_ std. dev. with ``ResourceFunction["PopulationStandardDeviation"] /@ lst``.

Answer (score 1):

```
In[9]:= lst = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {10}};

In[11]:= Map[StandardDeviation, lst] // N

During evaluation of In[11]:= StandardDeviation::shlen: The argument {10} should have at least two elements.

During evaluation of In[11]:= StandardDeviation::shlen: The argument {10.} should have at least two elements.

Out[11]= {0.707107, 1., 1.29099, StandardDeviation[{10.}]}
```

The standard deviation is meaningless for single element lists.  Not sure of the use case, but those lists should be dropped from your input list.

Comment: Or maybe `Map[If[Length@#<2, 0, StandardDeviation@#]&, lst]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought the standard deviation of a single number is 0, so why does Mathematica have trouble with it?

Comment: @Claudia take a look at [the reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardDeviation.html) which says this function is equivalent to `Sqrt[Variance[...]]`. Now see the definition of variance.

Comment: Ah, okay, it's because it'll be 0/0 in the variance definition. Thanks again!